# Eclipse ADT has stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, ide, eclipse-adt

Few hours back , I used my eclipse It was working properly but now it's not even opening ![1][1]

I had 2 different versions of eclipse , so tried to run both but none of them is working :(

Comment: Define `has stopped working`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even I faced same few days back**

Problem with the Workspace

Go to the Workspace that eclipse normally and  Remove metadata.log. This is a text file that should include some information about starting up, and the stack trace, if Java failed.